# Process list modifying elements in elisp

Tags: list, emacs, foreach, elisp

I am new to elisp and still learning how things I would write in C or Perl translate to corresponding elisp code. In a particular case, I need to process a list element-wise modifying these. I considered `dolist` but unlike for example Perl's `foreach` I cannot modify the original list values. I came up with the following code but it seems overly complicated (at least it does not look very readable to me):

```
(setq x '("a" "b" "c"))
(let ((p x))
  (while (car p)
    (setcar p (concat ">" (car p)))
    (setq p (cdr p))))
```

Is there a nicer way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... As I'm french, I'm not sure I can explain clearly what I mean...

"modify the original list values" is ambiguous, like "modifying the list elements".

Drew, in your example, you demonstrate that, with `dolist`, you can enumerate the list and, for each item in the list, you can apply a function (like `setcar`) which will change something *inside* this item.

Ok.

But, with `dolist`, you can NOT replace each item of the list by another item, like replacing `p` by `(concat ">" p)`.

In your example, the list `(2 2)` is `eq` to the list `(3 2)`.

So you could say that `bar` still points to the same cons cell, and that each element of `bar` also still points to the same cons cell.

We can say that you changed/modified the first element (in French, "vous avez changé *le* premier élément"), but you cannot say that you replaced the first item ("vous avez changé *de* premier élément").

Aamof, it's funny that, in french, there is just one different letter!

Anyway, you can't do it with `dolist`, but you can do it with `do`:

`(do ((p x (cdr p)))
     ((null p) x)
   (setcar p (concat ">" (car p))))`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you try to think about how to do what you want *without* modifying the list.  I.e. instead, returning another list.  For example:

```
(let ((newlist
       (mapcar (lambda (p) (concat ">" p))
               x)))
  ...use newlist...)
```

Comment: In this case, I definitely don't need the original list any more, and wanted to avoid copying... re-assigning mapcar results to the original list seemed list a waste, but I can see that it is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* true that `dolist` prevents you from modifying the list elements. The local variable that you declare in `dolist` gets bound to successive elements of the list - the *actual elements*, not copies of them. You can do whatever you want to modify those individual elements.

What you are likely confused about is the original list - or any list - that might contain those elements.

For example:

```
(defun foo (xs)
  (dolist (x xs) (setcar x 3)))

(setq bar '((2 2) (4 4 4) (6 6 6)))

(foo bar)
```

`C-h v bar` shows you that the list `bar` has indeed had each of its elements changed by the `dolist` code:

```
bar's value is 
((3 2)
 (3 4 4)
 (3 6 6))
```

`bar` still points to the same cons cell, but each element in the list has had its car set to 3.

---

**UPDATE** to reply to @duthen:

It's not about "each element of `bar` [still pointing] to the same cons cell".

It's about list modification.  Either you want to replace (or otherwise change) the actual elements in a particular list or you do not.  If you do, you can certainly do that using `dolist`.  The elements need not be conses.

But if you want to just replace the **elements** of a *particular list* that means that you do not want to modify the top-level list structure of that list.  Otherwise, you would be constructing a new list and not modifying only the elements of an existing list.

`dolist` does not, by itself, modify the top-level list structure of its list argument.  But it does not at all prevent you from changing the **elements** that are in that list.  And that includes changing **their** list structure, if they are themselves lists (conses), as in my example above.  By itself, `dolist` is not a tree operation.

Here is another example, where the list elements are strings.  Again, the elements themselves are modified - replaced, but the list containing them is the same (this list has only a top-level list structure).

```
(defun foo (xs)
  (dolist (x xs) (setf (aref x 0) ?$)))

(setq bar '("abc" "def" "ghij"))

(foo bar)
```

The list value of `bar` is indeed changed.  Its elements are not the same - they have been replaced by different values.  The list's cons cells are the same cons cells, but their cars do not have the same values.

`dolist` gives you access only to the individual *elements* of the list. It does not give you access to the top-level conses that make up the list itself.  You cannot use `dolist` to replace an element `"abc"` with an element `42`, because you cannot modify the former object to give the latter.  If you want to make a replacement like that then you need to *access the conses* of the list and not just the *elements* in the list.  The elements are only the cars of the top-level conses that make up the list.

The problem posed by the question was this: **"process a list element-wise modifying these"**.  That is entirely possible using `dolist`, as these examples show.  There is no way to modify `"abc"` to give you `42`.  If you want that kind of element replacement then you need to modify the list conses.

If something different was meant by the question then it is not clear.